# Unity8-Mir session doesn't start on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, session, mir, unity8

I seem to have a problem with running a Unity8-mir session on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed unity 8 mir according to the instructions as described at the webpage [OMGubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-unity-8-desktop-progress-video). After rebooting I can choose wether to run a standard session or Unity8-Mir as described on the same page. If I choose the latter option the screen turns black and the computer doesn't seem to respond anymore. I have to reset by alt-ctrl F1.

I am eager to know a solution to this problem, because I want to get familiar with Unity 8 for desktop.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Are you using open-source graphics drivers for your video card? The article states **the Unity8 Desktop Mir session we’re going to install only works with open-source graphics drivers, ideally open-source Intel graphics drivers... Proprietary video drivers do not yet offer the required level of support for Mir, so your experience if you’re using the binary block nVidia or AMD drivers will be somewhat disappointing.”**

Comment: I don't use any specific graphic drivers, certainly no propriety stuff. I use what comes default with ubuntu, I suppose.

Comment: What type of graphics card do you have?

Comment: Make sure you have `libpam-cgfs` package installed. Also make sure you are using open source drivers (though I'm not sure if anything other than Intel has really been tested at this point).

Comment: Yeah, perhaps the graphics thing is the problem. I installed unity 8 on a (not recent) Dell computer which seems to have AMD Caicos. Could this be the problem? libpam-cgfs is installed.